# List all directories recursively in a tree-like using AWK

Tags: awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all directories recursively in a tree-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227328/list-all-directories-recursively-in-a-tree-like)

I want to simulate a `tree` command using `awk` that displays all the directories recursively like this format:

```
|____
| |____0
| |____b
| |____c
| | |____a
| | |____w
```

And I made it using `sed`:

```
find ./ -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

But how can I do that using `awk`?

Comment: @shellter you asked me to show what have I tried, so here it is. It's not duplicated, since that one was closed.

Comment: you got someone else to write that code for you. Please show a little attempt at reading the awk manual or http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . I'll give you hint. Read about `gsub(/s/,"r", "str" or $fldNum)` . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont show any attempt to write something but I made something so I show you my soluiton. Expecting this can help you to learn some awk.

```
find ./ -type d -print | awk -F "/" '{for (i=1; i<=NF-2; i++){printf "| "} print "|____"$NF}'
```

This awk command use as separator "/" (-F option).

And, for each line print "| " as many time as the number of fields (NF) minus 2.
Finally it prints "|*_*" folowed by your last field ($NF).